# How do I change the youtube-dl date format in filenames? (From %Y%m%d to %Y-%m-%d)

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I would like to save [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) files in the upload date first. However, I dislike the default date format.

I'm working on a Python script. How can I change the dates from say:

20171024

to:

2017-10-24

I don't understand how I can do a date conversion when the output template is a string. Like so:

```
'%(upload_date)s_%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

If I could directly access (upload_date) and wrap it in a function to reformat the date, this would be simple.

```
date = %(upload_date)s
date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This obviously won't work, but I'm looking a solution that would be the equivalent of doing that.

Within [it's code](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/utils.py), I can see the youtube-dl uses the function [`unified_strdate`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/utils.py#L2931-L2956) to add the upload date. But, when I've tried changing the format to %Y-%m-%d I get a ValueError. (I'm also reluctant to mess around in a Python package and possibly lose those changes if I update the package).

Comment: @user2864740 Yes. But how does that work within youtube-dl. The output template must be entered as a string, and I don't know how to use a function within a string - to reformat the string.

Comment: @user2864740 I've looked into all of the above - before coming here to ask. I added a bit more detail to my question, and I hope that helps.

youtube-dl is a Python package. I've tried editing the package, but it's beyond my skill level. Unless someone informs me otherwise, I can't access the variables I need to reformat the date. And renaming the files after download may be the easiest option, but I came here to find out.

Comment: `%Y-%m-%` is missing the final `d`. IDK if that's the problem tho

Comment: @wjandrea I don't where it's missing. Would you point that out? But, that's not the issue. The issue is that %(upload_date)s is a variable that I don't know how to access. - just download pip download youtube_dl and you can recreate the issue using the embed example from the documentation.

Comment: *"when I've tried changing the format to %Y-%m-%"*

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks! I've edited the question.